# Trouble whith php rainbow text

Tags: php, text

I have trouble with php rainbow text functions.
When I run this function, the output text did not support vietnamese.

For example: **"tôi yêu em" ;**

```
<?php   
function rainbow($text)
{

    /*** initialize the return string ***/
    $ret = '';

    /*** an array of colors ***/
    $colors = array(
        'ff00ff', 'ff0099', 'ff0033', 'ff3300',        
        'ff9900', 'ffff00', '99ff00', '33ff00', 
        '00ff33', '00ff99', '00ffff', '0099ff',        
        '0033ff', '3300ff', '9900ff'
        );
    /*** a counter ***/
    $i = 0;    
    /*** get the length of the text ***/
    $textlength = strlen($text);    
    /*** loop over the text ***/
    while($i<=$textlength)
    {
        /*** loop through the colors ***/
        foreach($colors as $value)
        {
            if ($text[$i] != "")
            {
                $ret .= '<span style="color:#'.$value.';">'.$text[$i]."</span>";
            }
        $i++;
        }
    }
    /*** return the highlighted string ***/
    $ret = html_entity_decode($ret, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    return $ret;
}
echo rainbow('tôi yêu em');
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to get uninitialized string offset notices in any language with that function due to the way you're iterating over the string bytes + colors. Better to access the colors via an [InfiniteIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.infiniteiterator.php) which will just loop around and around.

Your specific problem with Vietnamese is that some of those characters are composed of multiple bytes. Functions like `strlen()` and accessing offsets via array brackets like `$text[$i]` are not multi-byte safe - they work on individual bytes rather than characters.

While it might be tempting to just use `mb_strlen()` in place of `strlen()` to get the number of characters rather than the number of bytes, and `mb_substr()` rather than `$text[$i]` to get a character rather than a byte, you'll still end up breaking up graphemes like `è` (which is here encoded as `e` followed by a [combining grave accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0300/index.htm).) A solution is to break up the string into an array with a regular expression.

---

#### Example:

```
function rainbow($text)
{
    $text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $return = '';

    $colors = new InfiniteIterator(
        new ArrayIterator(
            ['ff00ff', 'ff0099', 'ff0033', 'ff3300',
             'ff9900', 'ffff00', '99ff00', '33ff00',
             '00ff33', '00ff99', '00ffff', '0099ff',
             '0033ff', '3300ff', '9900ff']
        )
    );
    $colors->rewind();

    // Match any codepoint along with any combining marks.
    preg_match_all('/.\pM*+/su', $text, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[0] as $char)
    {
        if (preg_match('/^\pZ$/u', $char)) {
            // No need to color whitespace or invisible separators.
            $return .= $char;
        } else {
            $return .= "<span style='color:#{$colors->current()};'>$char</span>";
            $colors->next();
        }
    }

    return $return;
}

echo rainbow('tôi yêu em eve&#x300; foo baz');
```

---

#### Output:

```html
<span style='color:#ff00ff;'>t</span><span style='color:#ff0099;'>ô</span><span style='color:#ff0033;'>i</span> <span style='color:#ff3300;'>y</span><span style='color:#ff9900;'>ê</span><span style='color:#ffff00;'>u</span> <span style='color:#99ff00;'>e</span><span style='color:#33ff00;'>m</span> <span style='color:#00ff33;'>e</span><span style='color:#00ff99;'>v</span><span style='color:#00ffff;'>è</span> <span style='color:#0099ff;'>f</span><span style='color:#0033ff;'>o</span><span style='color:#3300ff;'>o</span> <span style='color:#9900ff;'>b</span><span style='color:#ff00ff;'>a</span><span style='color:#ff0099;'>z</span>
```